# In LUIS, is that possible to generate intent, utterance and proposed answering automatically?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am very new to Microsoft LUIS, and thinking the feasibility to utilize LUIS to build the Q&A ChatBot to provide the IT technical support to our users.

We have the 2-years support log in one email, my original idea is, to extract this support log to train/test LUIS, if the test result could be accepted, we may enable chatbot in SKYPE to provide the support to our users.

After I go through the following document or course:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/
https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:Microsoft+DEV328x+2T2018/course/

My understanding is, to build technical support chatbot, I have to:
1) Manually create the entities / intents / utterances in LUIS, then train / test LUIS, or achieve this by programming via LUIS API (it may like what is mentioned in the following thread:[Approaches to improve Microsoft ChatBot with each user conversation by learning from it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46886079/approaches-to-improve-microsoft-chatbot-with-each-user-conversation-by-learning)). The purpose of this step is , when users raise the questions, chatbot could match users' questions to the defined intents.
2) Customize the reactions based on the intents. And based on the intents identified in the above, answer the questions to users or redirect the questions to human if questions could not be found out.

My question is whether it is possible for LUIS to be trained by those 2 years' support log (fed in some formats such as in JSON), then automatically generate the intent / entities / utterance as well as answering for our test?

Your kind input or advises would be highly appreciated.

Best regards
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

> My question is whether it is possible for LUIS to be trained by those
>   2 years' support log (fed in some formats such as in JSON), then
>   automatically generate the intent / entities / utterance as well as
>   answering for our test?

Yes, by using [Batch Testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-batch-test) you can upload no more than 1000 utterances to test which will serve the purpose. In this case you have to create the intents and entities.

> My question is whether it is possible for LUIS to be trained by those
>   2 years' support log (fed in some formats such as in JSON), then
>   automatically generate the intent / entities / utterance as well as
>   answering for our test?

Yes, LUIS provides a programmatic API that does everything that the LUIS website does. This can save time when you have pre-existing data and it would be faster to create a LUIS [app programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-node-import-utterances-csv) than by entering information by hand.